# How to fetch data from restAPI and from localStorage at a time?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state

What I am doing is to load data from my local storage which I have fetched from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users. I am trying to create a react application in which I have added multiple users as a friend just like facebook. my friend list is in the file called UserInfo.js which code I have given bellow. then I tried to show friends corresponding to their id by comparing with the id which I tried to find from api call so that this can show me the matching users.
You can find my project here:  https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-dream-mp3is?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./UserInfo.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import fakedata from "../../fakedata";
import { getDatabaseCart } from "../../utilities/databaseManager";

const UserInfo = () => {
  // // using fakedata
  // const [users, setUsers] = useState(fakedata);

  // // declaring state while calling api
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  // declaring state while loading data from local storage
  const [friends, setFriends] = useState(users);

  // to load data from Api call
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setUsers(data));
  }, []);

  // to load data from local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedFriends = getDatabaseCart();
    const friendsId = Object.keys(savedFriends);
    const countFriends = friendsId.map((key) => {
      const friend = friends.find((fd) => fd.id == key);
      // console.log(friend);
      return friend;
    });
    setFriends(countFriends);
  }, [friends]);

  // console.log(friends);
  // console.log(users);

  return (
    <div className="userInfo-container">
      <div className="userInfo">
        {friends.map((friend) => (
          <div>
            <h4>Name: {friend.name}</h4>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default UserInfo;
```

I have created fakedata collecting data from jsonplaceholder and tested according to above method and it worked perfectly. but when I tried to load data API call, I got the following error:

1. the first error indicates that it can not read property of name which I tried to return from local Storage after matching the id with api call.

2.second error denotes which I can't understand in my case. I have tried abortCall to handle this error. the error gone but my problem still exits. what can I do now????

[image: first error]

[image: second error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hooks:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
//import "./UserInfo.css";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import fakedata from "../../fakedata";
import { getDatabaseCart } from "../../utilities/databaseManager";

const UserInfo = () => {
  // // using fakedata
  // const [users, setUsers] = useState(fakedata);

  // // declaring state while calling api
  const [users, setUsers] = useState([]);

  // declaring state while loading data from local storage
  const [friends, setFriends] = useState([]);

  // to load data from Api call
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((data) => setUsers(data));
  }, []);

  // to load data from local storage
  useEffect(() => {
    const savedFriends = getDatabaseCart();
    const friendsId = Object.keys(savedFriends);
    setFriends(friendsId);
  }, []);

  // console.log(friends);
  // console.log(users);

  return (
    <div className="userInfo-container">
      <div className="userInfo">
      {users.length > 0 && friends.map((friendId) => {
            const friend = users.find(user => user.id === parseInt(friendId));
            return (
            <div>
              <h4>Name: {friend && friend.name}</h4>
            </div>
          )})}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};


export default UserInfo;
```

Comment: Did you find this usefull ?

Comment: I have another problem in my same project which I forgot to mention is that in my UserCollection file you will find an error in line 20 where have tried to load the city of corresponding user. if you click show details button you will see an error saying can't read prop city of undefined. why is this happening??? though name, phone , email, website can be accessed

Comment: Work with <h3>Address: {friends.address != undefined ? friends.address.city : ''}</h3>. I think because the whole data are not entirely loaded on render.
Maybe check for friends too on lines above: friends && friends.name. and use useState like this: const [friends, setFriends] = useState(null) so while !friends data is empty.

Answer (score 0):

In the render, Friends return [{0:undefined}]. You are not setting friends correctly.

Comment: I don't understand

Comment: In your local store, the id is store as string so you can't compare with === because in user from server it's an integer

Comment: I make a new awnser, did you see it ?

Answer (score 0):

I make a Class version of your UserInfo component. It works like this.

```
import React from "react";
import { getDatabaseCart } from "../../utilities/databaseManager";

class UserInfo extends React.Component {
  state = {
    users: [],
    friends: []
  }
  
  componentDidMount = () => {
    this.getDataFromServer();
    this.getDateFromLocalStorage();
  }

  getDataFromServer = () => {
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users")
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => this.setState({users:data}));
  }

  getDateFromLocalStorage = () => {
    const savedFriends = getDatabaseCart();
    const friendsId = Object.keys(savedFriends);
    //console.log(friendsId)
    this.setState({friends:friendsId})
  }

  render() {
    const {users, friends} = this.state;
   // console.log('users',users, friends);
   // console.log('friends', friends);

    return (
      <div className="userInfo-container">
        <div className="userInfo">
          {users.length > 0 && friends.map((friendId) => {
            const friend = users.find(user => user.id === parseInt(friendId));
            return (
            <div>
              <h4>Name: {friend && friend.name}</h4>
            </div>
          )})}
        </div>
      </div>
    );

  }
}


export default UserInfo;
```

Note you have a promise for the 'fetch' so at first render and until users are fetched user = [] empty array. To avoid errors it's good to check the length of users before try to map friends.
You can remove the friend check here because if friends array is empty, there is nothing to map.

```
return (
  <div>
    <h4>Name: {friend.name}</h4>
  </div>
)
```

Now, it should be a list with ul and li.

Comment: I am not familiar with class component. Can you please provide solution  with functional component????

Comment: Sorry for that, but I'm not familiar with react hooks, I will try